# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin{\frac{a}{3^k}}}{3^k\sin{\frac{a}{3^{k-1}}}}$ (and another)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometry

> Compute
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\sin{\frac{a}{3^k}}}{3^k\sin{\frac{a}{3^{k-1}}}}\right)$$ and
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\sin{\frac{a}{3^k}}\sin{\frac{2a}{3^k}}}{3^k\sin{\frac{a}{3^{k-1}}}}\right)$$
> where $a$ is a positive real number.

I think the second limit may be solved by using the comparison criteria(limit comparison test), putting $-1 \le \sin{\frac{2a}{3^k}} \le 1$ and using the first limit. I suspect the first limit is $0$, so the second one should be $0$ too, but I might be wrong. I'm not sure how would you do the first one - I tried using the comparison test on the first one, but I didn't succeed. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sum is telescoping, due to $$\frac{\sin x\sin 2x}{\sin 3x}=\frac14(\cot x-3\cot 3x).$$ This easily gives $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\frac{a}{3^k}\sin\frac{2a}{3^k}}{3^k\sin\frac{a}{3^{k-1}}}=\frac14\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{3^k}\cot\frac{a}{3^k}-\frac{1}{3^{k-1}}\cot\frac{a}{3^{k-1}}\right)=\frac14\left(\frac{1}{3^n}\cot\frac{a}{3^n}-\cot a\right).$$
The first sum doesn't seem to. Trying to replace $\cot$ by $-\csc$ yields$$\frac14(3\csc 3x-\csc x)=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin 3x},$$ so it *would* telescope with the sine in the numerator *squared*.

Comment: That's a really clever approach! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any ideas regarding the first limit?

Comment: Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Neither limit can be zero, because the summand is not a function of $n$.  Only the index of summation is a function of the limiting variable; as such, it is necessary that each limit is bounded below by even just the first term in the sum, in as much as $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^k} > \frac{1}{3}.$$  I suspect there is no simple closed form solution for these sums, unless there is some nice telescoping identity I have missed.